# HashLocationStrategy on Angular2 beta 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I just want to know how to handle the HashlocationStrategy from angular2 beta 7? My Code from beta 3 does not work anymore.

What I have:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

and I get the error to set a base tag. But HashLocationStrategy did not require a base tag.

> EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of LocationStrategy! (RouterLink -> Router -> Location -> LocationStrategy).BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23094ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1185(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12591NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:13635collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13539Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13558zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:468lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:480lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:451(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:123microtask @ angular2.dev.js:13590Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:13558zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:262
>   angular2.dev.js:23083 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

How is HashLocationStrategy working in beta 7?

Regards

Comment: according to `angular2 changelog` there is no change for `HashlocationStrategy` for `beta-7`. check out here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta7-2016-02-18

Comment: Try to copy node_modules into your www root folder

Answer (score 1):

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

Add

```
<base href='/'>
```

to your markup.